# OpenShift 3.11 readiness and liveness probes chain

Tags: openshift

if a readiness probe fails, I know that the involved pod is isolated while not ready again.
Is the probe isolated from liveness check too?  I mean, if readiness isolates the pod, liveness fails?

thanx a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are two separate  checks. If readiness probe fails - it removes pod from service endpoints, so any traffic from other pods can't reach it by that that *service* name. If liveness probe fails - the pod is restarted. There is a brilliant [article in openshift blog](https://www.openshift.com/blog/liveness-and-readiness-probes), which summarizes this perfectly:

> Liveness : Under what circumstances is it appropriate to restart the
> pod?
>
> Readiness : under what circumstances should we take the pod out
> of the list of service endpoints so that it no longer responds to
> requests?

Readiness and liveness *probes* are done by kubelet and on specific pod, they have nothing to do with services at all. So if your are using something that bypasses kubernetes services to access your pods (don't do that) - you can easily connect by pod ip and port from within your cluster, since it's still working, even if readiness probe has failed.

Comment: so, if the readiness fails and the pod is removed from service endpoints, liveness can still get an "ok" answer?
thanx for your help

Comment: Yes, these are two completely different things which are not actually connected to each other. It depends on how you configured them. For example, if they are pointing to the same endpoint which starts responding with 500 error codes - liveness probe will kill pod after specified timeout. Depending on your settings It might happen even earlier than readiness check (doesn' sound practical though).